# Get No record found instead of Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in CodeIgniter **Controller**.It returns the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error when it enable to retrieve the data from the model. I want to display the **"No records found"** instead of the  Invalid argument.. error .

Here is my full code

**Controller**

```
function registered_customers_bod(){
        // get the data and pass to records Variable
        if($query =  $this->mod_reports->registered_customers_bod())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query ;
        }else{
            $data['records'] = 'No records found';
        }
        $data['report_name'] = $this->input->post('report_name');
        // load the view passing data Variable
        $this->load->view('admin/reports/user_reports_bod.html',$data);
    }
```

**View - user_reports_bod**

```
  <?php if (isset($records)) : $i = 1; $delivered_qty_total  = 0;   foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->cus_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->cus_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->cus_email; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->cus_phone; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->cus_mobile; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->cus_addr_city; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->user_status; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo gmdate("Y/m/d", $row->user_timestamp); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php  endforeach; ?>
<?php  endif; ?>
```

**Model**

```
function registered_customers_bod(){
        $to = new DateTime($this->input->post('to'));
        $from = new DateTime($this->input->post('from'));

        $this->db->select(array(
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_id',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_name',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_email',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_phone',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_no',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_street',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_city',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_status',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_reason_status',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_timestamp',
        ));
        $this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
        $this->db->join('tbl_user_registration', 'tbl_user_registration.user_id=tbl_customer_registration.user_id');
        $this->db->group_by("tbl_customer_registration.cus_id"); //view single record that contain two contact numbers
        $this->db->where('user_timestamp >=',$to->getTimestamp());
        $this->db->where('user_timestamp <=',$from->getTimestamp());
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: post model code too, and when `$data['records'] = 'No records found';` you will surely get **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if($query =  $this->mod_reports->registered_customers_bod()){
        $data['records'] = $query ;
    }else{
        $data['records'] = new stdClass(); // change here
    }
```

the reason behind the error is when no record is found from db your `$data['records']` is a **String** and which is surely `Invalid argument for foreach()`

and instead of `isset($records)` in view use `empty($records)`

and put else in view
**EDIT**

```
$arr = (array)$records;
if(!empty($arr)){
    $i = 1;
    $delivered_qty_total  = 0;
    foreach($records as $row) { ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php  echo $i++; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->cus_id; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->cus_name; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->cus_email; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->cus_phone; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->cus_mobile; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->cus_addr_city; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row->user_status; ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo gmdate("Y/m/d", $row->user_timestamp); ?></td>
     </tr>
 <?php } ?>
}
else { echo "No records found";}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I need to add else here  <?php if (isset($records)) : $i = 1; $delivered_qty_total  = 0;   foreach ($records as $row) : ?>

Comment: Thanks I applied it but still did not show the No records found message :(

Comment: then what is showed ? any errors ? check `var_dump($records)` before `if(!empty($records))` in view

Comment: ok i got it, and updated the answer, thanks. edit in view `$arr = (array)$records;if(!empty($arr))`